# WooCommerce add order admin hook for recalculate button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I'm looking to loop over all the products added to an order in the admin before the order is actually submitted. So far the only WooCommerce hooks I have found only allow you access the product items individually.

I was looking for a hook that would fire when a user clicks the recalculate button but actually it could trigger when a user adds a product, tax, shipping method, etc.. I just need to loop over all items added to the order so far.

At the moment I'm using `woocommerce_admin_order_item_values` hook but it's a self-contained loop so doesn't allow me to add all my '$item['product_id']' together.

```
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values( $null, $item, $absint ) { 
$item_ids = array($item['product_id']);
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3 );
```

You can also use - 
`woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta` Hook but this only accesses each item individually whereas I need to loop over each item in the summary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are number of hooks provided by WooCommerce, when you are clicking the **Recalculate** button. I'm listing here those hooks and it depends on you to choose among them according to your requirement.

$order = WC_Order object

```
    add_action("woocommerce_order_before_calculate_taxes", "custom_order_before_calculate_taxes", 10, 2);
    function custom_order_before_calculate_taxes($args, $order) {
        // Do something
    }

    add_action("woocommerce_order_item_after_calculate_taxes", "custom_order_item_after_calculate_taxes", 10, 2);
    function custom_order_item_after_calculate_taxes($order, $calculate_tax_for) {
       // Do something
    }

    add_action("woocommerce_before_order_object_save", "custom_before_order_object_save", 10, 2);
    function custom_before_order_object_save($order, $data_store) {
      // Do something
    }

    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_before_calculate_totals', "custom_order_before_calculate_totals", 10, 2);
    function custom_order_before_calculate_totals($and_taxes, $order ) {
      // Do something
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_after_calculate_totals', "custom_order_after_calculate_totals", 10, 2);
    function custom_order_after_calculate_totals($and_taxes, $order) {
      //Do something
    }

    add_filter("woocommerce_order_is_vat_exempt", function(){
       return $boolean;
    });

    add_filter("woocommerce_order_get_total", "custom_order_get_total", 10, 2);
    function custom_order_get_total($value, $order) {
      //do somethig
      return $value;
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, none of these have access to the products or items added to the order. hey just return the status of the order e.g. currency, shipping, payment methods etc...

Comment: You want to do something , when you are clicking the Recalculate button, right? If yes there are the only hooks attached with this action. These all contain a Order object and you can do anything with it.
If not, please let me know the exact instance where you want to hook and the motto of the action.

Comment: dont forget to add this `if( did_action( '[FILTER_NAME]' ) >= 2 ) return;` to avoid infinite loops.